# Fullcalendar events shows wrongly in chrome until a window resize/zoom for example

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, fullcalendar

Calendar events loads fine in FF. But I have a problem in Chrome because it loads meeting events in wrong positions when I'm loading the page for first time. Once after the window resized or zooming it resets to correct position.  When I'm look into inspect element for a meeting starting at **12AM** by the class of a anchor link

> 'fc-time-grid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-short',

it shows CSS as,

```
element.style {
top: 519.75px;
bottom: -541.75px;
z-index: 1;
left: 0%;
right: 0%;
```

}

Once I do resize it changed to correct position and the CSS shows as,

```
element.style {
top: 0px;
bottom: -103px;
z-index: 1;
left: 0%;
right: 0%;
```

}

I gone through some codes in fullcalendar.js I found some comments like

> Works when called after initial render, after a window resize/zoom for example.
>   under Seg Position Utils.

Now how can I load events in correct position by the first time itself?

Comment: can you make a fiddle which demonstrates the issue please? I've never experienced anything like this, and certainly never had to change/override the fullCalendar CSS to deal with any problems, let alone browser-specific ones. It sounds like there could maybe be something else conflicting here, or it's a very specific set of circumstances.

Comment: @ADyson yes I guess. And I dont know what do you want exactly?

Comment: build a working example I can access which shows it, e.g. using JSFiddle or CodePen. Because I can't reproduce the problem. If I can see it I might be able to find the cause.